# how to write async web api for get method in web api 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

showing warning of "this asynch method lacks await". kindly suggest where to add await in my asynch method?

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeDetails(string id,string StartDate, string EndDate)
        {
            DateTime sd = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
            DateTime ed = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
            using (EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities ())
            {
                try
                {
                    return Ok(db.employees.Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= sd && x.TimeStamp <= ed && x.DeviceImei ==id).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToListAsync());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Sorry Error Found!!!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in the return statement where you are using `ToListAsync()`

```
return Ok(await db.employees.Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= sd && x.TimeStamp <= ed && x.DeviceImei ==id).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToListAsync());
```